# Lucas-Kanade image alignment algorithm implementation not converging?

Tags: python, algorithm, opencv, image-processing

I've recently been attempting to implement the Lucas-Kanade algorithm for image alignment, as detailed in this paper here: https://www.ri.cmu.edu/pub_files/pub3/baker_simon_2004_1/baker_simon_2004_1.pdf

I've managed to implement the algorithm detailed in page 4 of the paper I linked, but the loss doesn't seem to converge. I've been looking over my code and my math, and can't seem to figure out where I might be going wrong.

What I've tried so far is implementing the entire algorithm, and re-doing my math for calculating the Jacobian of the warp, as well as just general checking of my code.

My code is below, as well as a more readable version on Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/j28mUV65

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def calculate_steepest_descent(grad_x_warped, grad_y_warped, h):
    rows, columns = grad_x_warped.shape
    steepest_descent = np.zeros((rows, columns, 8))
    warp_jacobian = np.zeros((2, 8)) # 2 x 8 because it's a homography, would be 2 x 6 if it was affine
    current_gradient = np.zeros((1, 2))

    # Convert homography matrix into parameter array for better readability with the math functions later
    p = h.flatten()

    for y in range(rows):
        for x in range(columns):
            # Calculate Jacobian of the warp at each pixel, which contains the partial derivatives of the
            # warp parameters with respect to x and y coordinates, evaluated at the current value
            # of parameters
            common_denominator = (p[6]*x + p[7]*y + 1)
            warp_jacobian[0, 0] = (x) / common_denominator
            warp_jacobian[0, 1] = (y) / common_denominator
            warp_jacobian[0, 2] = (1) / common_denominator
            warp_jacobian[0, 3] = 0
            warp_jacobian[0, 4] = 0
            warp_jacobian[0, 5] = 0
            warp_jacobian[0, 6] = (-(p[0]*(x**2) + p[1]*x*y + p[2]*x)) / (common_denominator ** 2)
            warp_jacobian[0, 7] = (-(p[1]*(y**2) + p[0]*x*y + p[2]*y)) / (common_denominator ** 2)
            warp_jacobian[1, 0] = 0
            warp_jacobian[1, 1] = 0
            warp_jacobian[1, 2] = 0
            warp_jacobian[1, 3] = (x) / common_denominator
            warp_jacobian[1, 4] = (y) / common_denominator
            warp_jacobian[1, 5] = (1) / common_denominator
            warp_jacobian[1, 6] = (-(p[3]*(x**2) + p[4]*x*y + p[5]*x)) / (common_denominator ** 2)
            warp_jacobian[1, 7] = (-(p[4]*(y**2) + p[3]*x*y + p[5]*y)) / (common_denominator ** 2)

            # Get the x and y gradient intensity values corresponding to the current pixel location
            current_gradient[0, 0] = grad_x_warped[y, x]
            current_gradient[0, 1] = grad_y_warped[y, x]

            # Calculate full Jacobian (aka steepest descent image) at current pixel value
            steepest_descent[y, x, :] = np.dot(current_gradient, warp_jacobian)

    return steepest_descent

def calculate_hessian(steepest_descent):
    rows, columns, channels = steepest_descent.shape
    hessian = np.zeros((channels, channels))

    for y in range(rows):
        for x in range(columns):
            steepest_descent_single = steepest_descent[y, x, :][np.newaxis, :]
            steepest_descent_single_transpose = np.transpose(steepest_descent_single)
            hessian_current = np.dot(steepest_descent_single_transpose, steepest_descent_single)
            hessian += hessian_current

    return hessian

def calculate_sd_param_updates(steepest_descent, img_error):
    rows, columns, channels = steepest_descent.shape
    sd_param_updates = np.zeros((8, 1))

    for y in range(rows):
        for x in range(columns):
            steepest_descent_single = steepest_descent[y, x, :][np.newaxis, :]
            steepest_descent_single_transpose = np.transpose(steepest_descent_single)
            img_error_single = img_error[y, x]
            sd_param_updates += np.dot(steepest_descent_single_transpose, img_error_single)

    return sd_param_updates

def calculate_final_param_updates(sd_param_updates, hessian):
    hessian_inverse = np.linalg.inv(hessian)
    final_param_updates = np.dot(hessian_inverse, sd_param_updates)

    return final_param_updates

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Load image
    reference = cv2.imread('test.png')
    reference = cv2.cvtColor(reference, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Generate template as small block from within reference image using homography
    # 'h' is the ground truth homography for warping reference image onto template image
    template_size = (100, 100)
    h = np.float32([[1, 0, -100],[0, 1, -100],[0, 0, 1]])
    h_ground_truth = h.copy()
    template = cv2.warpPerspective(reference, h, template_size)

    # Convert template corner points to reference image coordinate plane
    template_corners = np.array([[0, 0],[0, 100],[100, 100],[100, 0]])
    h_inverse = np.linalg.inv(h)
    reference_corners = cv2.perspectiveTransform(np.array([template_corners], dtype='float32'), h_inverse)

    # Small perturbation to ground truth homography
    h_mod = np.random.uniform(low=-1.0, high=1.0, size=(h.shape))
    h_mod = np.array([[1, 1, 1],[1, 1, 1],[1, 1, 1]])
    h_mod[0, 0] = h_mod[0, 0] * 0
    h_mod[0, 1] = -h_mod[0, 1] * 0
    h_mod[0, 2] = h_mod[0, 2] * 10
    h_mod[1, 0] = h_mod[1, 0] * 0
    h_mod[1, 1] = h_mod[1, 1] * 0
    h_mod[1, 2] = h_mod[1, 2] * 10
    h_mod[2, 0] = h_mod[2, 0] * 0
    h_mod[2, 1] = h_mod[2, 1] * 0
    h_mod[2, 2] = h_mod[2, 1] * 0
    h = h + h_mod

    # Warp reference image to template image based on initial perturbed homography
    reference_transformed = cv2.warpPerspective(reference, h, template_size)

    # ##############################
    # Lucas-Kanade algorithm below
    # This is supposed to calculate the homography that undoes the small perturbation
    # and returns a homography as close as possible to the ground truth homography
    # ##############################

    # Precompute image gradients
    grad_x = cv2.Sobel(reference,cv2.CV_64F,1,0,ksize=1)
    grad_y = cv2.Sobel(reference,cv2.CV_64F,0,1,ksize=1)

    # Loop algorithm for given # of steps
    for i in range(1000):
        # Step 1
        # Warp reference image onto coordinate frame of template
        reference_transformed = cv2.warpPerspective(reference, h, template_size)

        # Step 2
        # Compute error image
        img_error = template - reference_transformed
        # fig_overlay = plt.figure()
        # ax1 = fig_overlay.add_subplot(1,3,1)
        # plt.imshow(img_warped)
        # ax2 = fig_overlay.add_subplot(1,3,2)
        # plt.imshow(template)
        # ax3 = fig_overlay.add_subplot(1,3,3)
        # plt.imshow(img_error)
        # plt.show()

        # Step 3
        # Warp the gradients
        grad_x_warped = cv2.warpPerspective(grad_x, h, template_size)
        grad_y_warped = cv2.warpPerspective(grad_y, h, template_size)

        # Step 4 & 5
        # Use Jacobian of warp to calculate steepest descent images
        steepest_descent = calculate_steepest_descent(grad_x_warped, grad_y_warped, h)

        # fig_overlay = plt.figure()
        # ax1 = fig_overlay.add_subplot(1,8,1)
        # plt.imshow(steepest_descent[:, :, 0])
        # ax2 = fig_overlay.add_subplot(1,8,2)
        # plt.imshow(steepest_descent[:, :, 1])
        # ax3 = fig_overlay.add_subplot(1,8,3)
        # plt.imshow(steepest_descent[:, :, 2])
        # ax4 = fig_overlay.add_subplot(1,8,4)
        # plt.imshow(steepest_descent[:, :, 3])
        # ax5 = fig_overlay.add_subplot(1,8,5)
        # plt.imshow(steepest_descent[:, :, 4])
        # ax6 = fig_overlay.add_subplot(1,8,6)
        # plt.imshow(steepest_descent[:, :, 5])
        # ax7 = fig_overlay.add_subplot(1,8,7)
        # plt.imshow(steepest_descent[:, :, 6])
        # ax8 = fig_overlay.add_subplot(1,8,8)
        # plt.imshow(steepest_descent[:, :, 7])
        # plt.show()

        # Step 6
        # Compute Hessian matrix
        hessian = calculate_hessian(steepest_descent)

        # Step 7
        # Compute steepest descent parameter updates by
        # dot producting error image with steepest descent images
        sd_param_updates = calculate_sd_param_updates(steepest_descent, img_error)

        # Step 8
        # Compute final parameter updates
        final_param_updates = calculate_final_param_updates(sd_param_updates, hessian)

        # Step 9
        # Update the parameters
        h = h.reshape(-1,1)
        h[:-1] += final_param_updates
        h = h.reshape(3,3)

        # Step 10
        # Calculate norm of parameter updates
        final_param_update_norm = np.linalg.norm(final_param_updates)

        print("Final Param Norm: {}".format(final_param_update_norm))

        reference_transformed = cv2.warpPerspective(reference, h, template_size)
        cv2.imwrite('warps/warp_{}.png'.format(i), reference_transformed)

    # Warp source image to destination based on homography
    reference_transformed = cv2.warpPerspective(reference, h, template_size)
    cv2.imwrite('final_warp.png', reference_transformed)
```

It should just need a reference image to test with.

The expected result is that the algorithm converges to a homography that matches the ground truth homography I calculate in the code, but the loss just seems to explode instead and I end up with a totally incorrect homography.

Answer (score 0):

**This should be a comment since I am not certain is the full cause of your problem**

*But it might be part of it*

To solve a system of linear equations don't compute the inverse

```
hessian_inverse = np.linalg.inv(hessian)
```

and then multiply by it

```
final_param_updates = np.dot(hessian_inverse, sd_param_updates)
```

This is both wasteful and can cause more numerical instability than solving systems of linear equations normally have.

Instead use the method `solve`.

Computing the inverse will repeat some of the operations needed to do `solve` for each of the columns of the identity matrix. None of those operations is needed.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't solve my problem, but thank you for pointing this out! I've corrected it as you suggested, definitely makes more sense than what I was currently doing